# How to copy value of two sub list into a single list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, sublist

I have a collection of list

```
List<List<int>> FS=new List<List<int>>()
```

I've added Values to each list. Now my `FS` Look like `FS={{1,2,3},{5,7},{3}}`.

How to combine the values to first two sub list into a single new list?
my need to get like `{1,2,3,5,7}`

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work?

Comment: Do you want to combine the first two lists *because* the last one only have value of `3` which is already in the first two lists, or no matter what is the value, you want only the first two lists?

Comment: `two sub list into a single new list?` what about the third one?

Comment: Why does your example have three lists but you want to only merge the first two?  This question is very confusing.

Comment: no matter what is the value, iwant only the first two lists or random two list @Ian

Comment: no matter what is the value, iwant only the first two lists or random two list @Eric Lippert

Comment: @Ritz: I think it would be less confusing if your third list contained values which were not in your first two lists.

Comment: No matter what contents are there in third list @Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FS` has always has 2 or more items, use `List.AddRange()`:

```
FS[0].AddRange(FS[1]);
```

**Edit**

The above example would edit the original list. If you want a new list you should create a new one and use `AddRange` to add values to it:

```
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
newList.AddRange(FS[0]);
newList.AddRange(FS[1]);
```

Comment: Perhaps you also want to add that this FS[0].AddRange(FS[1]) must also be assigned to a new list to avoid having {{1,2,3,5,7},{5,7},{3}} in the originally List.

Comment: Thanks @Ian You're right. Updated my answer with new details.

Answer (score 1):

Use both `GetRange` and `SelectMany`:

```
FS = FS.GetRange(0, 2).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

`GetRange` is to get the `N` (in your case `N = 2`) number of elements from the `List`.

```
{{1,2,3},{5,7},{3}} => {{1,2,3},{5,7}}
```

`SelectMany` is used to flatten the `List<List<int>>` into `List<int>`.

```
{{1,2,3},{5,7}} => {1,2,3,5,7}
```

Comment: @AlexJolig you are right. I updated my answer. And I think your answer, as long as the number of element is two or above, will work too.

Comment: yeah. I deleted the comment. anyways, you're a wise guy since I saw you first time with 2k reputations and I respect you :)

Comment: @AlexJolig I originally thought that the OP does not want to get the third list because he already has the value in it (which is 3), thus I suggested `Distinct`, but I appear to be wrong after I confirmed with the OP.

Comment: @AlexJolig oh, I just joined SO for few months. So it must be around that time.. And, pleased to meet you too! :) Though I have seen you a couple of times before - mostly when you quickly edit new posts - This may be the first time We exchange our comments like this. So, pleased to meet you. :)

Comment: Now That I look at your answer, it's way better than mine. Also I'm amazed with your achievements in just two months!!! Maybe your next John Skeet!

Comment: No, no. I am just a typical programmer who learn from SO - in these few months since my project allows me to learn whatever I want during this time. While Jon Skeet is a Guru of Gurus. He is way beyond normal programmers that people start to make "facts" about him (which you probably ever read too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts ) :) If you haven't read that. Check it out. It is really funny!

Comment: Yupe read that. Still think that you're very smart and incredible programmer. Getting 8K reputation in just **two month** is not an ordinary thing

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to merge first two `Lists`, you can use `Take` to get first two collections and later you can use `SelectMany` to linear collection of collections.

```
FS.Take(2).SelectMany(e=>e);
```

To eliminate the duplicates use  `Distinct`

```
FS.Take(2).SelectMany(e=>e).Distinct();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEHBnt)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine all three lists and select only the distinct items you can do an union with distinct.

```
 FS.SelectMany(list => list).Distinct();
```

If only you want to combine first two lists. then you have to resort filtering only two items or selecting top 2 items on the list then do an union.

```
FS.Take(2).SelectMany(list => list).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'AddRange' method in List

```
List<int> combinedList = new List<int>(FS[0]);
combinedList.AddRange(FS[1]);
```